# unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl boost::tss_cleanup_implemented(void)"

Tags: c++, boost

I was very surprised when I tried to search this error as I got only 4 results, two of which seem to be in Chinese. I am getting this error when compiling my project and boost sources alltogether. I searched the boost library and found this:

```
namespace boost
{
    /*
    This file is a "null" implementation of tss cleanup; it's
    purpose is to to eliminate link errors in cases
    where it is known that tss cleanup is not needed.
    */

    void tss_cleanup_implemented(void)
    {
        /*
        This function's sole purpose is to cause a link error in cases where
        automatic tss cleanup is not implemented by Boost.Threads as a
        reminder that user code is responsible for calling the necessary
        functions at the appropriate times (and for implementing an a
        tss_cleanup_implemented() function to eliminate the linker's
        missing symbol error).

        If Boost.Threads later implements automatic tss cleanup in cases
        where it currently doesn't (which is the plan), the duplicate
        symbol error will warn the user that their custom solution is no
        longer needed and can be removed.
        */
    }

}
```

My question is what's tss cleanup, why is it needed and how do I implement it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about TSS, but to fix this linker error, you need to define

```
BOOST_THREAD_WIN32
```

and

```
BOOST_THREAD_BUILD_LIB
```

so `boost/thread/src/win32/tss_pe.cpp` implements the missing function (empty).

I assume there are few results on the Internet for this question, because the build scenario is rare. Most people do not build boost within their own project, but build boost with b2.